# batch file to get file from last modified folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that compares two files and uses xcopy to copy the file if the time stamp is different. So it goes something like this:

```
set sourcefiletime=
for %%X in (%Source%) do set sourcefiletime=%%~tX
set targetfiletime=
for %%X in (%Local%) do set targetfiletime=%%~tX
if "%sourcefiletime%" == "%targetfiletime%" goto noUpdate
xcopy...
```

The trouble I have now is that the folder structure has changed from always being a constant folder name to having different names based on date and time. And there may be multiple folders.

e.g.

```
"Build_20160411_105904"
"Build_20160410_155605"
"Build_20160410_021104"
...
```

Is there any way I can get my batch file to check the "last modified" folder and grab the file from there? If it helps, the file I need will always have the same name, so can I check the parent folder's directories for the last modified file instead?

Apologies if something similar has been asked before.

Comment: And the file name in the build folder will be always the same?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "last modified" folder: do you want to gather the creation/modification date of the folder, or do you want to parse the date/time portion of the folder names? note that they could differ...

Comment: I am presuming that the last time the folder was modified is the last time a file was uploaded. All these folders are used for are to upload an installer and thats it. I don't really care what the folders are called, I just need the file in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested

```
@echo off
set "build_dir=c:\builds"
set "source_filename=build.result"

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('dir /b /a:d /o:-d /t:w "%build_dir%"') do (
  set "last_build_dir=%%~f#"
  goto :break
)
:break
set "source_file=%last_build_dir%\%source_filename%"
```

this will get the file with name `%source_filename%` from the last modified folder in `%build_dir%` . And then you can reuse your code.

Comment: Seems to do exactly what I want it do do. Thanks!

Comment: Had to add a bit extra in as my source was a unc path and the code above gets the last modified from where you are running the batch file from

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last modified folder name within C:\apps\test directory then you can put below code snippet in a batch script and execute it which will print the name of the last modified folder name.

```
@echo OFF

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir "C:\apps\test" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') do (
    set latestModifiedFolderName=%%i
    goto :break
)

:break
echo Latest modified folder within C:\apps\test directory is %latestModifiedFolderName%
```